# Understand Frustum parameters in Pangolin visualizer library

Tags: c++, frustum, pangolin

I am rendering a camera frustum using the `glDrawFrustum()` method available in pangolin. This is the open source code [here](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/blob/d484494645cb7361374ac0ef6b27e9ee6feffbd7/components/pango_opengl/include/pangolin/gl/gldraw.h#L253)

In general, I am aware that the frustum parameters are `frustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far)`

But pangolin has its function defined as below.

```
inline void glDrawFrustum( GLfloat u0, GLfloat v0, GLfloat fu, GLfloat fv, int w, int h, GLfloat scale )
{
    const GLfloat xl = scale * u0;
    const GLfloat xh = scale * (w*fu + u0);
    const GLfloat yl = scale * v0;
    const GLfloat yh = scale * (h*fv + v0);

    const GLfloat verts[] = {
        xl,yl,scale,  xh,yl,scale,
        xh,yh,scale,  xl,yh,scale,
        xl,yl,scale,  0,0,0,
        xh,yl,scale,  0,0,0,
        xl,yh,scale,  0,0,0,
        xh,yh,scale
    };

    glDrawVertices(11, verts, GL_LINE_STRIP, 3);
}
```

**Question 1** - Do the parameters correspond to left, right, top, bottom, near and far ??

**Question 2** - Here are my parameters for `pangolin::glDrawFrustum`

```
float left = -1.f;  // X axis related
float right = 1.f;
float bottom = -1.f;
float top = 1.f;   // Y axis related
float near = -1.f;
float far = 1.f;

pangolin::glDrawFrustum(left, right, top, bottom, near, far);
```

[image: Sqewed image]

I get a skewed image. How do I get a symmetric frustum. I assume I am providing symmetric parameters in my code.